# SimpleDateFormat parse error position

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I'd like to notificate user if he entered date out of range(for example month = 22). But dateFormat stores in global settings file, so I don't know the exactly position of month field in input string. I've tried to use getErrorOffset() method of ParseException, but it always returns end position (10) of the input string

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    try
    {
        sdf.parse("22/12/2009");
    }
    catch (ParseException ex)
    {
        ex.getErrorOffset();
    }
```

Is there any solution?
thx

Answer (score 1):

You want to turn lenient parsing off:

```
sdf.setLenient(false);
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29)

Comment: I want to tell user in which part of date he made a mistake.

Comment: And replace exception 'Unparseable date: "22/12/2009"' to 'Month number should be within 1 and 12'

Answer (score 0):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29):

> If an error occurs, then the index of pos is not changed, the error index of pos is set to the index of the character where the error occurred, and null is returned.

Comment: `       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
        sdf.parse("22/12/2012", pos);
        ` this code returns 10 both in index and errorindex